# Passing parameters to exe from ini file

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to launch a project.
Please tell me how to transfer parameters from such an ini file to exe?

```
[Data]
User = "Test"
UID = 1234
[Path]
Dir = E:\Test
Exe = test.exe
```

So I try to assign them

```
   process.StartInfo.FileName = BasePath + "\\Loader.exe";
           process.StartInfo.Arguments = Resources.Start;
           process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = BasePath;
```

Please tell me how to implement this?
The ini file must be transferred, it does not accept a simple line. Or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Where is the INI file?

Comment: @mjwills , In resources the exe of my program

Comment: So your issue is how to read from the INI file?

Comment: @mjwills My problem is that I do not understand how to transfer the entire file in the exe of the program I need.
Initially, that program was run through the "test.bat" inside it "test.exe params.ini" but I need to change it slightly and run it through my program.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, this code should work
(replace "Loader.exe" and "inifile.ini" with proper names of your files):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(BasePath + "\\Loader.exe");
psi.Arguments = BasePath + "\\inifile.ini";
psi.WorkingDirectory = BasePath;
try
{
    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
    MessageBox.Show("Error:\n" + ex.InnerException, "Run Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: I am writing in bad English) I'm sorry)
My ini is inside resources in exe